# How to get the MySQL version

Tags: mysql, awk

have the following string.

```
[root@fedoravm001 ~]# mysql -V

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

From the above I can able to parse and get the required version number as follows:

```
[root@fedoravm001 ~]# mysql -V | awk '{print $5 }' 
5.5.38,
```

I don't want the comma at the end of the string 5.5.38

> answer is: mysql -V | awk '{print $5}' | awk 'gsub(",$","")'

Comment: pass it to `cut -f1 -d','` i.e. 

`mysql -V|awk '{print $5}'|cut -f1 -d','`

Comment: `rpm -q --qf '%{version}\n'` will get you the RPM package version too if that's of use. Use `awk '{sub(/,/, "",$5); print $5}'` in your pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `grep`

```
mysql -V | grep -Eo "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
```

One or more digits followed by a dot followed by one or more digits followed by a dot followed by one or more digits.

Or using `awk` with alternate field separators, of commas or spaces:

```
mysql -V | awk -F'[ ,]+' '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the extra ',' with tr command like:

```
mysql -V | awk '{print $5 }' | tr -d ,
```

Comment: mysql -V | awk '{print $5}' | awk 'gsub(",$","")'

Comment: Better in one awk mysql -V | awk '{gsub(",$", "", $5); print $5}'

Comment: thank you almas shaikh for answering my question , thanks for quick response.

Comment: You are welcome @tony. Dont forget to close this question by accepting any of these answer's whichever you think has helped you so that it could help others later on.

Comment: have you tried anytime starting mysql with different user.like ls -l /var/lib/mysql given means we get -rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    16384 Nov 22 01:33 aria_log.00000001, instead we can do like this right -rw-rw----. 1 joe joe    16384 Nov 22 01:33 aria_log.00000001 i'm able to get it but starting of mysql have little problem

Comment: @tony i didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

All in one `awk`

```
mysql -V | awk '{sub(/,$/,"",$5);print $5}'
```